# SQL SP is not working giving error Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_APP_FORM_GET_ITEMLIST 

    @Table_Name VARCHAR(100),
    @Email_Frequency_INDays VARCHAR(50)

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE  @RESULTS AS TABLE(Form_Status VARCHAR(100), Created_By VARCHAR(100) )
    DECLARE @query_select AS nvarchar(500) = ' SELECT FORM_STATUS,RECORD_CREATED_BY FROM dbo.' + @Table_Name


      INSERT INTO @RESULTS
       SELECT @query_select

    SELECT *
    FROM @RESULTS;

END
GO
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific. Perhaps <sql-server>?)

Comment: Looks like Sybase, or SQL Server to me.

Comment: Mandatory link: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute your variable using `sp_executesql` :

```
INSERT INTO @RESULTS (Form_Status, Created_By)
EXEC sp_executesql @query_select;
```

Note : Always qualify *column* names while using `INSERT INTO . .`.